# mailsystem module does not appear in the selection field for HTML Mail module class

Tags: 7, emails

when I go to the `mailsystem` module configuration, only two selection fields appear

I do not know why this behavior can be given, there is some option that makes this disappear. I have installed the `mailsystem` and `htmlmail` modules

**What I see in the site where the selection field is missing**

[image]

**What should be shown (what I need)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below where you show in your screenshot, see the "New Class" field set. 
Expand that

For the **Class to use for the format() (link is external) method** field select HTMLMailSystem

**Class to use for the mail() (link is external) method** select SmtpMailSystem

Save the form.

The new class will be available for use to set the Site Default.